# Need to remove \n and \" from inside of a string

Tags: c#

Earlier I had help with a user telling me how to remove text within angle brackets inside of a string. This user proposed and I accepted the following:

```
var a = "some text follows<p><p>Give the following test text:</p>"
var newString = Regex.Replace(a, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Now I realize there's just a bit more I need to remove. Looking at the contents of the string I still see in the final string some instances of backslash n and backslash double quote. \n  and  \"

Is there an easy way that I can remove any instances of \n  and  \" that appear in my string. Ideally by adding some more to the above Regex?

Comment: HTML parsing with RegEx goes down a slippery slope.

Comment: You want to remove this extra text from within the tags or from the whole body? Those values don't appear in `a`. Did you accept the other answer?

Comment: have you seen this http://www.wellho.net/regex/java.html

Comment: do you want to remove backslash n and backslash double quote or the escaped versions new line and `"`?

Comment: If you are actually concerned with parsing different bits of html consider http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ a generic answer could save you a lot of pain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I played around on rubular.com and came up with this as a regular expression.  You can keep adding additional checks using the vertical pipe as a separator:

```
<(.|\n)*?>|\\n|\\"
```

So your code would look like this (though you might need to escape the extra double quote in the regex):

```
var a = "some text follows<p><p>Give the \n following \"test\" text:</p>" 
var newString = Regex.Replace(a, @"<(.|\n)*?>|\\n|\\"", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't verify the code itself, just the regex.  Glad it's working!

Answer (score 3):

What if you use `String.Replace` function

```
myString.Replace("\n", "");
myString.Replace("\\"", "");
```

Can't you do this work around?

Comment: Don't forget that you can chain these together, and also that you need to assign the result bck to your variable like so : `myString = myString.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\\"", "");`

Comment: Take a look at your regex. Now back to the string replace. Now back to your regex. Now back to the string replace. Sadly, it isn't a string replace, but if you stopped overcomplicating things and used basic solutions it could like this. Look down, back up. Where are you? You're sitting in front of readable, maintainable code. What's in your hand, back to me. I have it, it's ease and relaxation. Look again, the ease and relaxation is now yours. Anything is possible when you stop overusing regex on simple problems like this. I'm on a chair.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
newString.Replace("\"","").Replace("\n","");
```

Still will try to do it regex way.

Comment: -1 Duplicate answer unluckily. Also that first string just reads as a lone quotation mark once parsed.